# How to Format Excel Speadsheet for Garden Planning

Tags: excel

I want to use Excel (or another free program) to create a map of my Vegetable Garden. Essentially what I need to do is be able to have excel save a layout given a specific day of the year.

On SHEET 1, I will create a table for the given variables. For ease, let's say each vegetable has a variable called 'DAY TO MATURITY'. Then, on SHEET 2, I want to be able to "sow" a vegetable in a specific cell(s) on the sheet, and have that stored there for a length of time equal to 'DAY TO MATURITY'.

I can do this already in the sense that I can create 366 sheets and label them one per day and copy past days onto newer ones, but I'd love to know if there is a way to do it on one sheet. Ideally, I would choose a date and the spreadsheet would should the garden layout for that day.

[image]

Comment: Interesting project - this could definitely be done. You'd essentially only have 1 worksheet that you write to, and this is where you'd indicate what cell on your garden has what plant and for how long. I can put a small example together for you.

Comment: Voting to close this question as it is not related to writing code, whatsoever. MDR, please take a look at the purpose of this site.

Comment: @Dwirony, that would be incredibly helpful. This project is for personal use (not a student or a proprietor). I just want to be able to maximize my personal garden with computer science. 

Teylyn, please don't close this thread. I think the answer will have a coding solution, I just don't know what it is.